# Trying To Change only each Label's title in angular Chartjs

Tags: angular, hover, chart.js, tooltip, mousehover

I have a little bit of struggle on using the callback function in angular charts.

I have my original bar chart as:
[image]

here the popup for each label shows the label title (bt_helpdesk...) and in yellow box the Success Prediction Count (5247) and in Red Box Failed Prediction Count(310).
I added a call back function in which:
when mouse is hovered on each label popup as above, it will show the full lable title otherwise it will show only 10 chars and add 2 dots at the end of each label title.
my call back function is:

```
 callbacks: {
  label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
   data.labels[tooltipItems.index] = tooltipLabels[tooltipItems.index];
   return '';
  },
}
```

here I changed each label name. after adding the callback function I have output as:
[image]
here it only shows the label title, I want it to show the dataset values as well as:

[image]

can anyone help me out on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to call afterLabel callback not label.

Comment: Is this not an answer?

Comment: it is the answer, just after posting it, i found the solution so i wanted to share it with all the folks :)